# Apollo fetchMore updated props not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an array of "posts" coming from a graphql query, and I'm trying to work in pagination using offset + limit as described in the [apollo docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/pagination.html#numbered-pages). Currently pressing "loadMore" updates the query and the result in `fetchMoreResult` is correct. Furthermore, the concatenated `newResults` appears correctly when logged. Maybe I'm making an incorrect assumption, but the way I understood the docs was that the new resulting `posts` would be automatically passed into my `TestComponent` and re-render. Is this incorrect?

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { GetPosts } from 'app/graphql';

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // I would expect this to log the new props after press "loadMore"
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 40}}>
        <Text onPress={this.props.loadMore}>Push me</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default graphql(GetPosts, {
  options: () => ({
    variables: {
      offset: 0,
      limit: 1
    }
  }),
  props: ({ ownProps, data }) => {
    return {
      ...ownProps,
      posts: data.posts,
      loadMore: () => {
        return data.fetchMore({
          variables: {
            offset: 1,
            limit: 1
          },
          updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {            
            if (!fetchMoreResult) {
              return previousResult;
            }
            const newResult = Object.assign({}, previousResult, {
              posts: [...previousResult.posts, ...fetchMoreResult.posts]
            });
            console.log(newResult);
            return newResult;
          },
        })
      }
    };
  }
})(TestComponent);
```

**Edit (4/11/17)**
I failed to explain that my query `GetPosts` included union types which seems like it could possibly be the issue because if I remove them, the update works as expected. I've opened an issue with package in hopes for more clarity: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/602

Comment: You could try some of the things folks have tried here to see: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/549

Answer (score -2):

For re rendering the `TestComponent` you have change the state of the component.

you can basically do

```
this.setState({

posts: [old values + new values],

})
```

And then in render function you can call this by `this.state.posts`

Comment: new props should be passed in by the `graphql` higher order component triggering a re-rende.